# Conditional Statement: separate custom objects with an object header in an array (Code example)

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, conditional-statements

```
data (
    {
    "name" = "Conway";
    "country" = "England";
},
    {
    "name" = "Bale";
    "country" = "Wales";
},
    {
    "name" = "Stephens";
    "country" = "Scotland";
},
    {
   "name" = "Michael";
    "country" = "England";
},
    {
   "name" = "Pedro";
    "country" = "Spain";
},
    {
    "name" = "Patrick";
    "country" = "England";
},
    {
    "name" = "John";
    "country" = "Ireland";
},
    {
    "name" = "Bob";
    "country" = "Ireland";

}
)
```

I have a JSON array I am parsing. The goal is to display this content in a picker view. However the picker view is custom, the list will appear like this:

```
 **Ireland**
 John
 Bob
 **England**
 Conway
 Michael
 Patrick
```

etc etc.

As you can see however, the JSON to be parsed is not organised nicely and separated by headers, so I have the joy of doing it in the app instead :( but I am up for the challenge.

I have a player object.

```
Player.h
NSString * name;
NSString * country;
BOOL isHeader;
```

The block of code is below that I use to loop through the contents of the downloaded JSON. My current implementation is not ideal, and a bit confusing. But I couldn't think of any other way, I am always open to solutions to do this a quicker way.

I loop through the contents, if its the first time the object is being done, then isHeader is set to true.

The final Array is to contain all the objects from the initial array, but categorised by the country they are from, the country header is also set as a `Player` object, but with `isHeader` true. I am open to alternative ways of doing this. The end goal for each object to be separated with a header. I would preferably like to use an array of objects as well, but open to better practice suggestions.

```
for (int i=0; i < mArray.count; i++) {

                                if (i==0) {
                                    Player * pPlayer = mArray[i];

                                    pPlayer.isHeader=YES;
                                    [headerArray addObject:pPlayer];

                                    [catArray addObject:pPlayer];

                                }
                                else{

                                    BOOL newHeader=YES;

                                    for (int j=0; j<headerArray.count; j++) {

                                        Player * jPlayer =mArray[i];
                                        Player * headerPlayer = headerArray[j];

                                        if ([headerPlayer.country isEqualToString:jPlayer.country]) {
                                            newHeader=NO;

                                            jPlayer.isHeader=NO;
                                            [catArray addObject:jPlayer];
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (newHeader==YES) {
                                        Player * hPlayer = mArray[i];


                                        hPlayer.isHeader=YES;
                                        [headerArray addObject:hPlayer];


                                        [catArray addObject:hPlayer];
                                    }

                                }

                            }


                            for (int k=0; k<headerArray.count; k++) {

                                [finalArray addObject:headerArray[k]];
                                for (int y=0; y<catArray.count; y++) {


                                    Player *cPlayer = catArray[y];
                                    Player *hPlayer = headerArray[k];

                                    if ([hPlayer.country isEqualToString:cPlayer.country]) {

                                        [finalArray addObject:cPlayer];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

The current result is:

```
**Ireland**
**Ireland**
Bob
**England**
**England**
Michael
Patrick
```

So something is definitely wrong with my conditional statement.

Comment: Concentrate on the data structures first; you'll want to create a dictionary of arrays (key=country name, value=mutable array with names).  *Then* you'll want an array to order the countries (if the picker is anything like a tableview, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *players = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 
for(Player *player in mArray) {
  NSString *country = player.country;
  NSMutableArray *playersArray = players[country];
  if(!playersArray) {
    playersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  [playersArray addObject:player.name];
  players[country] = playersArray;
}
```

I think this should do it, although I'll admit I haven't tested it.
As Droppy said, if you want the headers ordered you'll have to put them in an array. You can get the headers via `[players allKeys];` and order them using `sortUsingComparator:` -- then traverse the `players` dictionary getting each key in turn from the sorted array.